# ReadAsAsync keeps returning null WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, get, caliburn.micro

Im trying to get the data that has a bin of "0001"

```
string bin = "0001"
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string uri = $"https://localhost:44316/api/Bplo?bin={bin}";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<BploModel>();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
```

- Status Code is 200 but result comes back as null:
  [image: 1]
- I checked if the problem was the endpoint, but it was working great:
  [image: 2]
- I tried checking if I misspelled the model:
  [image: 3]

tried adding it on a List but still returns null.

Comment: You need to prove your payload is what you think it is. Use Fiddler, or get the string instead

Comment: This is a HTTP response. Are you sure the response contains a BploModel object and not a byte array or s string? It looks like the content couldn't be casted to the genetic parameter type. Maybe you should try an original HttpContent method like ReadAsStringAsync instead. You need need to manually deserialize any byte data. A data type like a class is a language detail. HTTP specification does not support language specific days types.

Comment: As @thegeneral says, use Fiddler. But, since all you are doing is a GET, just test things out in a brower to see what the server is returning

Comment: @BionicCode You're right, My Payload does not match. Code works after I convert the byte data to object. Thank you very much!! save me from another 4hrs of debugging, How do I mark your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, it seems your endpoint is replying with a reasonable JSON, your Model seems okay, and you are getting a HTTP 200 from the call.

I dug into [the framework's `ReadAsAsync<>` method](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/ba26cfbfbf958d548e4c0a96e853250f13450dc6/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs#L137), and broken down its component so you can step through and see which part is failing for you:

```
public static async Task<T> MyReadAsAsync<T>(string url)
{
    var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw up if unsuccessful
    
    /*** ReadAsAsync<> starts here ***/

    // Check the header for content type
    var contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType;
    // Expected "application/json"
    Debug.WriteLine($"ContentType: {contentType}");
    
    // Get available formatters in the system
    var formatters = new MediaTypeFormatterCollection();
    // Expected: more than 0
    Debug.WriteLine($"Formatters: {formatters.Count}");
    
    // Find the appropriate formatter for the content
    var formatter = formatters.FindReader(typeof(T), contentType);
    // Expected: JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    Debug.WriteLine($"Formatter: {formatter}");

    // Check the formatter
    var canRead = formatter.CanReadType(typeof(T));
    // Expected: true
    Debug.WriteLine($"CanReadType: {canRead}");

    // Check the stream
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    // Expected: length of your JSON
    Debug.WriteLine($"StreamLength: {stream.Length}");
    // Expected: your JSON here
    Debug.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
        (stream as System.IO.MemoryStream)?.ToArray()));

    // Check the formatter reading and converting 
    // from the stream into an object
    var resultObj = await formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(
        typeof(T), stream, response.Content, null);
    // Expected: an object of your type
    Debug.WriteLine($"Obj: {resultObj}");
    
    // Cast to the proper type
    var result = (T)resultObj;
    // Expected: an object of your type
    Debug.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    
    return result;
}
```

You can call the method by passing in your url (also see [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/awAkZF) for a working test against a public endpoint)

```
var result = await MyReadAsAsync<BploModel>("https://YOUR_ENDPOINT");
```

Answer (score -1):

just add .Result() at the end of ReasAsAsync

Comment: Still Giving Errors

Comment: FWIW, its rarely acceptable to call `Result` or `Wait` in modern .Net, there is always a better approach, and that usually is `await`

Comment: @TheGeneral do I need to make an Interface and assign the properties 1 by 1?